# MySQL Replication w/SSL -- How does it work?

Tags: mysql, ssl, replication

thank you for the help.

I was hoping that someone could shed some light on how mysql uses SSL.  I am currently up and running with master/slave replication, however, I'd like to make sure that the traffic is secured through SSL.  The instructions that I am using are here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions-ssl.html

The question that I have is does the master or the slave store and use the .key?

When I configure the slave, I use the CHANGE MASTER TO command and specify the CA, PATH, CERT, and KEY.  Are these the files that are housed on my master server?

I'm also told to specify in my.cnf the [client] CA, CERT, and KEY.  Again, are these the files on the master?

I guess I'm just not understanding the workflow.  It would seem that the slave would contact the master, the master would require ssl, then the slave would request the public key from the master to establish the secure connection.

can anyone help me with this?  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it shows in [6.3.6.3. Using SSL Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-ssl-connections.html), client/s should have it's/their own ca, cert, and key.

> Similar options are used on the client side, although in this case, --ssl-cert and --ssl-key identify the client public and private key. Note that the Certificate Authority certificate, if specified, must be the same as used by the server.